# Is it possible to reference from one static variable to another (within classes)?

Tags: php

Is it anyhow possible within a PHP class to reference from one static variable to another?

```
class EmployeeDAO
{
    private static $FIND_ALL = 'SELECT * FROM employee';

    private static $FIND_BY_NAME = self::$FIND_ALL . // This is not allowed!
        ' WHERE employee.name LIKE :name';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting form [php 5.6](https://secure.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.0) you can do like this:

```
class EmployeeDAO
{
    const FIND_ALL = 'SELECT * FROM employee';

    const FIND_BY_NAME = self::FIND_ALL .
        ' WHERE employee.name LIKE :name';
}
```

Comment: I see, the only way to make it private is starting from 7.1?

Comment: And if I implement it using private static functions? Is it freaky? Will PHP-developers curse me?

Answer (score 1):

A property declared as static cannot be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can). For compatibility with PHP 4, if no visibility declaration is used, then the property or method will be treated as if it was declared as public.

[PHP: Static Keyword - Manual](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: And what if I use private static functions to return the appropriate strings and to reference to each other?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is an appreciated way, but I could solve it this way:

```
private static function sql_findAll()
{
    return 'SELECT * FROM employee';
}

private static function sql_findByName()
{
    return self::sql_findAll() .
        ' WHERE employee.name LIKE :name';
}
```